# html link does not redirect to the expected page

Tags: html, razor, hyperlink

I have the following razor markup

```
<a href="@Model.WebsiteAddress" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><span>@Model.WebsiteAddress</span></a>
```

Where `WebsiteAddress` is a field which the user entered. Many times the users just write their website address without the `http://` part. For example: `WebsiteAddress = www.google.com`

Now when the user clicks on the link if it does not contain `http://` then a new tab is opened with MY website address as prefix to the actual WebsiteAddress. For example: `http://www.mywebsite.com/www.google.com`

What can I do so that the address will always linked to the right website?

Comment: Then you should either suggest on the form that they dont include the http:// then you can href="http://@Model.WebsiteAddress"

Comment: "WebsiteAddress is a field which the user entered [...]" - so can you (visibly) prefix the field with (undeletable) `http://`, so the string entered by the user will always be in the correct format?

Comment: your browser will automatically treat it as a part of the local domain if you don't specify http://. In your code behind you can just prepend http:// if it doesn't contain that. You could also specify a format string on your client side, or use JQUERY to format the string and prepend http://

Comment: I can add http:// when necessary, but many times it is not actually http but https, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know razor but I believe this will do the trick, make a new variable where you strip http and https out completely:

```
@{ var strippedUrl = @Model.WebsiteAddress.Replace("http", "").Replace("https", ""); }
```

then hard code `http://` before the url

```
<a href="http://@strippedUrl" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><span>@Model.WebsiteAddress</span></a>
```

the only caveat to this method is that you're forcing `http` over `https`